# project numpy array to aitoff projection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an (as yet incomplete) image of the whole sky. In order to display it properly it needs to be projected onto an ellipse (specifically an Aitoff projection).

I have tried various versions of this:

```
plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.imshow(image, vmin=0.004, vmax=0.01, extent=[0,360,-90,90])
plt.show()
```

...and have tried changing the values in the extent kwarg to radians, as well as using pcolor or pcolormesh instead of imshow.

These have given me: an empty Aitoff plot, various Aitoff plots with all or part of my image sitting inside it, but not filling it, or an Aitoff plot with a small part of my image (one or two pixels by the looks of things) completely filling it.

[My whole image sitting within a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwrFz.png)

[The unprojected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0x46.png)

I also do not have access to things like Basemap or astroproj as I'm using a machine owned by my university.

Edit: As was pointed out by another user the above example is not  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. Below is a version which should be:

```
A=np.random.rand(180,360)
plt.imshow(A)
plt.show()

plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.pcolormesh(A)
plt.show()
```

I want the entire image generated in the `plt.imshow()` command to be projected in the Aitoff figure. Instead only a few pixels are. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `imshow`, but `pcolormesh` works as expected. If you have a problem you need to provide a [mcve] in order to get help here.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I've added a new example that should be minimal, complete and verifiable.
(I'm new here, apologies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `imshow` in non-rectilinear projections will mostly fail. But instead `pcolormesh` may be used.

The aitoff projection ranges from -π to π in horizontal and from -π/2 to π/2 in vertical direction. This is the range of values to use when plotting the `pcolormesh` plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread("house.jpg")
x = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,im.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2,im.shape[0])
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.subplot(111, projection="aitoff")
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y[::-1],im[:,:,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]